# Image size for all screen devices

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio, image-size

I have `PSD`, resolution of that is `1080X1920`, it contains a `Dot` image whose resolution is `22X22`.

I have cropped that image and put it in my `res` folder.

My question is how would Android know that the image is for `1080X1920` screen. It would open the same image bigger in `small` screen and smaller in `2560x1440` resolution.

**Is there a way other than putting different images for each screen sizes to tell android to use the image for specific screen size and scale for other `screens`**

Comment: You can manage `Height and Width` of image using `dimen.xml` by passing different dimen to each values folder.

Comment: You can use this tool to simply generate image files in different dpis for different screen sizes: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use directly https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

> For example, two devices that both report a screen size of normal
>   might have actual screen sizes and aspect ratios that are slightly
>   different when measured by hand. Similarly, two devices that report a
>   screen density of hdpi might have real pixel densities that are
>   slightly different. Android makes these differences abstract to
>   applications, so you can provide UI designed for the generalized sizes
>   and densities and let the system handle any final adjustments as
>   necessary

You have to create different dimen , layout , images and icon files to support all devices.

**changes in screen density.**

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

**Make this layout files, so that it will be same for all devices**.

Give padding ,margin ,font and all properties as per devices.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

**For Layout** ,

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

---

**For Images**

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

---

**For Icon**

```
res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

**For Launcher icon**

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)
```

Checkout [Dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) and 
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html) Official Documentaion.

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio has a plugin called "Batch Drawable" install in your Android studio. This help to create images of different size.

Steps To import:
File-->Settings-->Plugin-->Browse Repositories-->Click install button.

Restart your Android studio, then you will be able to find "Batch Drawable" inside the file menu of Android Studio.

Link: https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin

Answer (score 1):

There is no more you have to do, just put the different resolution files into different drawable-xxx file is okay. Remember that all the pics MUST HAVE the same name but Android will not automatically to match the screen size for each pic is the file name is not matched. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

put largescale image in drawable folder.