# What is the best way to design Resources in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-resources, android-resolution

There is a formula written in Android documentation

```
 px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

I have an Image whose dimensions are `35px X 35px`.I have a few questions regarding this.

> 1. Should i convert this image into different `dp's` and put it in resources.
> 2. Does Android uses this formula to convert images into `dp`? or we need to use this formula to convert all images into `DP`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) it gives you all the needed resources made up from your image. Then you will place them into your `drawable-xxx` directories.

Answer (score 1):

> 1> Yes, you have to convert that 35x * 35x to support other devices
>
> 2> you dont need to go throught that trouble or use that formula, get
>   it directly from available sources.

Check https://design.google.com/resources/ and http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

check previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207973/2826147