# How to fit png/jpg images on any screen without decreasing quality?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I know it's bit tricky and still thinking whether is it possible or not, but i want to make my image to adjust without decreasing in image quality on any android device when i used **vector Drawable** it was pretty convenient but sometimes size of vectors are not memory efficient so i don't want to use them.Though i want to know if there is any way to adjust simple **PNG** or **JPEG** files irrespective of resolution and screen size in Android?

If anyone can give me way,it would be great help !!

Comment: I am wondering if you can use scaleType provided as attribute to ImageView to get your job done. There are various scaleType available like center, centerCrop, centerInside, fitCenter, fitEnd, fitStart, fitXY, matrix.

Comment: suggestion to use of PNG files, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207973/2826147

Comment: ok i already tried it but by making this folders and putting different files is not a solution really @AmitVaghela

Comment: that will solve your this issue

Answer (score 1):

Use Resize Image View (Custom Image View)

```
  public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {
    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ResizableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        // get drawable from imageview
        if (d == null) {
            super.setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }

        int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        // get height and width of the drawable
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        // get width and height extracts the size from the supplied measure specification.
        float imageRatio = 0.0F;
        if (imageHeight > 0) {
            imageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
        }
        float sizeRatio = 0.0F;
        if (heightSize > 0) {
            sizeRatio = widthSize / heightSize;
        }

        int width;
        int height;
        if (imageRatio >= sizeRatio) {
            // set width to maximum allowed
            width = widthSize;
            // scale height
            height = width * imageHeight / imageWidth;
        } else {
            // set height to maximum allowed
            height = heightSize;
            // scale width
            width = height * imageWidth / imageHeight;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        // This method must be called to store the measured width and measured height. Failing to do so will trigger an exception at measurement time
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it will work on all density for all devices and resolutions ? and can you make it more understandable by putting comments in it ? please it would be great help @ChiragArora

Comment: Please check, If you want to understand more then please check below link

http://www.ryadel.com/en/android-proportionally-stretch-imageview-fit-whole-screen-width-maintaining-aspect-ratio/

Comment: Ok yeah very helpful @Chirag