# Scrollview on Relative layout overlapping on toolbar

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

My scrollview on my .xml is working but it's overlapping on the toolbar I can't press back on the hierarchy anymore and also I just updated my android studio to 2.2 Beta idk if this is the problem.

Here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.DetailActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etResDate"
    android:editable="false"
    android:hint="Reservation Date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPickup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etResTime"
    android:editable="false"
    android:hint="Reservation Time"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etResDate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPickup"
    android:hint="Pickup Location"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPoster"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etReturnTime"
    android:editable="false"
    android:hint="Return Time"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etReturnDate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rent"
    android:id="@+id/btnRent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etReturnTime"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvCarModel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvCarType"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCarModel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCarModel"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCarModel" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvCapacity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCarType"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCarType"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCarType" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvFuelType"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCapacity"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvPoster"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvPlateNumber" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvFuelType"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFuelType"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvFuelType" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etReturnDate"
    android:editable="false"
    android:hint="Return Date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etResTime"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot of my overlapping scrollview]

Comment: Please provide a screen shot.

Comment: @AmitVaghela - I've updated the code I forgot to add my scrollview. Srry.

Comment: @jaydroider - theres a screenshot sir i've updated it. :)

Comment: @J.Shmoe Why you have taken this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` remove it and check.

Comment: @jaydroider - It's still the same sir.

Comment: check [single image for different screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207973/2826147)

Comment: @jaydroider - its okay now sir. I just placed the `app:layout_behavior‌​="@string/appbar_scro‌​lling_view_behavior"` on the scrollview not on the relative layout. Thank you sir! please convert the comment to an answer. :)

Comment: @J.Shmoe Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove this `app:layout_behavior‌​="@string/appbar_scro‌​lling_view_behavior"` from `Relative Layout`.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.DetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do something like the XML code below or just simply add your EditText/TextView component in between NestedScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/addtimesheetlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.DetailActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<!--Add your EditText here-->


</LinearLayout><!--Main layout ends-->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.DetailActivity">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etResDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etPickup"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="Reservation Date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etResTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etResDate"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="Reservation Time" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPickup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPoster"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Pickup Location"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etReturnTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etReturnDate"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="Return Time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etReturnTime"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Rent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCarModel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCarType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCarModel"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCarModel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCarModel"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCapacity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCarType"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCarType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCarType"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFuelType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCapacity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPoster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPlateNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFuelType"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvFuelType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvFuelType"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etReturnDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etResTime"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="Return Date" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

check if this helps