# Layout files with different resolutions not working

Tags: android, layout, resolution

I am working with different screen resoultions for android devices, i have added the layout folders for default, small and xlarge size devices and also the dimens as below :

```
  <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin_small">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin_small">8dp</dimen>

<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin_large">64dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin_large">64dp</dimen>
```

and added the below code into the manifest file :

```
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

folder format for layouts looks as :

res-

--layout

--layout-large

--layout-small

The layout file consists dimensions specific to the resolution and everything is being followed as per the [guideline](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) 
But the changes are not reflected on the actual devices with different resolutions. i.e. I always see small margin on all devices. Am i missing something.

The grade version I am using is, 2.14.1

Comment: instead of creating layout for different resolutions, you can use drawable and values for that means just create a single layout folder and multiple for drawable and values according to resolutions

Comment: How are you confirming this? What exactly are you seeing, what are you expecting? Give concrete examples of WHAT you think it SHOULD be.

Comment: What do you mean, changes not applied in actual device ? Give some examples.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207973/2826147

Comment: @Darpan S. Raut is there any reasone to use small,large.etc instead standard Android screen density folders ? (mdpi, hdpi) etc ? Did you declared in each layout folder, same name layout with different dimension according to dimension which you have listed ?

Comment: That's weird. Maybe try to use densities instead of sizes. Could you upload xml layout file which this bug concerns...