# Placing an imageview at the center of the layout regardless of screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and so this is me experimenting with my layouts. I want to place an **`imageview` at the center of the layout screen** and it should be at the center **`regardless of device size or resolutions`**. Additionally, the `imageview` should automatically scale up in size depending on the **device sizes**. How should I go about it ?

This is what I tried so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.inducesmile.androidcameraapi2.AndroidCameraApi">
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="take_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: Replace your ImageView with https://stackoverflow.com/a/47711400/6314513

Comment: have you checked any of below answers yet?

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.inducesmile.androidcameraapi2.AndroidCameraApi">
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="take_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've added this line in your `imageView` `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to try with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="take_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Remove `android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_takepicture"`//as this will align imageview to end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="take_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Lesley Odundo regardless of device size or resolutions this will work

Comment: you need to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207973/2826147 if you want to support all types of different resolutions devices

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `ImageView` with,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
```